# Is there just one word, 哈密瓜, for both honeydew melons and cantaloupes?

Tags: vocabulary

I couldn't find distinct words referring to green and orange melons. Would it just be 橙色的 and 绿色的哈密瓜?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honeydew is also known as:

> 蜜露甜瓜

which can be shortened to:

> 蜜瓜

---

[Wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8E%9A%E7%9A%AE%E7%94%9C%E7%93%9C) also proposes the following terms:

- 罗马甜瓜 (Cantaloupe)
- 白兰瓜 (Honeydew)

哈密瓜 all the meanwhile is also interchangeable with Hami Melon.

蜜瓜 can also be a term for muskmelons in general.

Chinese is very malleable so YMMV & you might just be better off with something like 绿哈密瓜.

Comment: Can't that also refer to the orange-colored melon, or is there a separate word for that?

Comment: @KMan They are just different types of 哈密瓜, so we refer them both as 哈密瓜，different areas might have different names for different types, but it's not that important.

Comment: @Mindless But if one really, really wanted an orange one instead of a green one? 橙色的哈密瓜？

Answer (score 0):

Names probably depends on location.

In Hong Kong, green Honeydew is 蜜瓜 and orange Cantaloupe is 哈密瓜.

蜜瓜 comes from the name Honeydew. 蜜 is honey in Chinese. It is very sweet.

哈密瓜 comes from a place name 哈密 in Northwestern China. It is less sweet.